# Lease mismatch LeaseExpiredException

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, iteration, sequencefile

I have seen some posts on this topic, but I could not figure the fix to my problem. I am using Hadoop version Hadoop 2.0.0-cdh4.2.0, and java version "1.7.0_09-icedtea".  I am running a program that utilizes counters to control interations in a simple mapreduce example. I also employ sequence files for communicating data. The code is simple: It starts with a number, say, 3. The mapper doesn't modify the number, but simply transmits the value; the reducer reduces the number by 1 each time it runs. The counter is increamented, if the number is greater than zero. Eventually, the nummber must decrease to 0, and the program should stop at that point. However, I always get the following error after the first iteration (during the second iteration):

```
" Running job: job_201304151408_0181
13/05/10 18:55:54 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 0% reduce 0%
13/05/10 18:56:03 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 100% reduce 0%
13/05/10 18:56:10 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 100% reduce 33%

13/05/10 18:56:11 INFO mapred.JobClient: Task Id : attempt_201304151408_0181_r_000002_0, Status : FAILED
org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException(org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.LeaseExpiredException): Lease mismatch on /user/harsha/iterone/import/data owned by DFSClient_NONMAPREDUCE_-592566041_1 but is accessed by DFSClient_NONMAPREDUCE_-965911637_1"
```

Can anyone please help? Thank you.

Regards...

Answer (score 0):

Usually Lease Mismatch happens if we are trying to write into a file which is not existing.

Please check if `/user/harsha/iterone/import/data` is in `hdfs`.

Is that a file?